# weight painting clothes Problem

Tags: weight-painting

Im sorry if this question is stupid but it seem that when moving my character in pose mode the cloth seems to move faster than the forearm even though the weight applied to the cloth and the forearm is the same

[image]

[image]

what can i do to fix this problem?

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots i have shared the blend file , please take a look

Comment: it looks like the vest doesn't want to parent correctly, so maybe use a modifier like Data Transfer or delete all its vertex groups and weight paint. Also make sur that you have an edge loop where the vest is supposed to bend (elbow)